# Google Maps API v3- Create a marker property that contains content from other properties?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

This should be extremely easy... I'm trying to make a marker property `totalContent` that contains the content of three other variables to make it easier to search for markers based on multiple filters.

The current code looks like this:

```
downloadUrl("genxml.php", function(data) {
    var xml = data.responseXML;
    var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");

    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
        var country = markers[i].getAttribute("country");
        var skills = markers[i].getAttribute("skills");
        var interests = markers[i].getAttribute("interests");
        var languages = markers[i].getAttribute("languages");
        var totalContent = skills + " "+interests+" "+languages+ " ";
    //window.alert(totalContent);  --this works, it contains all the content--
        var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
            parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")), 
            parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("long")));

            var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + country + "<br/><b>Skills:</b>" + skills + "<br/><b>Interests:</b>" + interests + "<br/><b>Languages:</b>" + languages;

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: point,
                skills: skills,
                interests: interests,
                languages: languages,
                totalContent: totalContent // is this proper?

        });
        marker.skills = skills;
        marker.interests = interests;
        marker.languages = languages;
        marker.totalContent = totalContent;  //the top three works, but this doesn't?

        gmarkers.push(marker);

    }


});
```

When I try to call gmarkers[i][totalContent] at any other point in the script or even in the Chrome console, totalContent is showing up as undefined.  How do I resolve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the data to yield doing gmarkers[i].totalContent instead of gmarkers[i][totalContent].  Might be helpful for someone else.

Comment: The "property name" is a string.  This `gmarkers[i]['totalContent']` should have worked as well.